Fastest way to run Steiner tree on large graph?
I have a very large graph (25GB, 35 million edges) and a collection of nodes. I want to find a tree that has all of those nodes; a tree that minimizes the number of edges but maximizes the number of the nodes covered.
My approach was to use Steiner but was wondering if there is a faster way to process or alternative algorithms that is faster.
I'm currently using NetworkX steiner_tree function to analyze but it's taking way too long.
Q1) Is there a reliable PCST in python out there? I know R has it one but not sure if it is faster than NetworkX one.
Q2) Is there a better algorithm that I can use that is PCST but faster?
Currently using NetworkX steiner_tree to analyze. The graph is undirected, with no edge weight.
def load_graph(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t', low_memory=False)
    G = nx.Graph()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        G.add_edge(row['subject'], row['object'], predicate=row['predicate'])  # Include predicate if needed
    return G

# Find largest connected component containing as many c_id
def get_subgraph(graph, node_list):
    subgraph_nodes = set()
    for node in node_list:
        for cc in nx.connected_components(graph):
            if node in cc:
                subgraph_nodes.update(cc)
                break
    return graph.subgraph(subgraph_nodes).copy()

def find_pcst_tree(graph, node_list):
    # Approximate the Steiner tree
    steiner_tree_approx = steiner_tree(graph, node_list)
    return steiner_tree_approx

# Load the graph from TSV file
graph_file_path ='~/graph_edge.tsv'  # graph file path
graph = load_graph(graph_file_path)

# List of nodes
node_list = ['ID_TYPE1:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE2:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE3:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE4:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE5:XXXXXXX', 
             'ID_TYPE6:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE7:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE8:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE9:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE10:XXXXXXX', 
             'ID_TYPE11:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE12:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE13:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE14:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE15:XXXXXXX', 
             'ID_TYPE16:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE17:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE18:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE19:XXXXXXX', 'ID_TYPE20:XXXXXXX', 
             'ID_TYPE21:XXXXXXX'] # list of nodes that needs to be covered

subgraph = get_subgraph(graph, node_list)

# Check which terminal nodes are in the subgraph
terminals_in_subgraph = [node for node in node_list if node in subgraph]

# Find the Steiner tree using the approximation algorithm
steiner_tree = find_pcst_tree(subgraph, terminals_in_subgraph)

# Visualize the graph and the tree
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))

# Plot the entire graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)  # Compute layout
nx.draw(graph, pos, with_labels=False, node_size=10, 
        node_color='lightgray', edge_color='gray', alpha=0.5)

# Plot the Prize-Collecting Steiner Tree
nx.draw_networkx_edges(pcst_tree, pos, edge_color='blue', width=2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(pcst_tree, pos, nodelist=terminals_in_subgraph, 
                       node_color='red', node_size=100)

plt.title("PCST")
plt.show()


Your question is off-topic. Still, have you checked pcst-fast (written in C++) ?

multiple questions and no code to reproduce your problem this is off-topic or needs more details. If you try to give more specifics to your question we can try a bit more. Please provide the code and how specifically you are calling (here)[https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-2.8.6/_modules/networkx/algorithms/approximation/steinertree.html#steiner_tree] you can get a litlte detail of its implementation maybe something can be optimizade looking at your specific usage... ?

@imbr uploaded code.

@Timeless, that's my next attempt. Is it good for a very large graph? When I looked through the posts here, people use < 1M or even 100k nodes. From the link you provided On instances with up to 350,000 edges, the algorithm typically runs in under 2 seconds on a standard laptop computer from 2010. So I guess it's a bit fast, could try it and see...

Yes, you can always give it a try ;). Also, you should avoid using iterrows to build your graph. Update load_graph by removing the loop and making G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "subject", "object", "predicate").

@beaker minimize the number of edges and maximizes the node coverage. The goal is to use node_list as a subgraph proxy and examine how well (or not) that subgraph aligns with the bigger graph. e.g. does the those list of nodes (subgraph) connect relatively short path compared to the bigger graph

@beaker I don't think MST works well for a subset of vertices. Given a graph and subset of vertices (nodes), Steiner Tree passes through the given subset.

If the Steiner tree contains some vertices that are not in the subset but are used to connect, then one can assume or accept that the subset has a shorter link than what would be in the bigger graph.

@beaker, the edges don't have any weight, which I mentioned in the main body.

Which is why I'm confused why adding 2 edges instead of 1 would minimize the number of edges. But clearly I'm not understanding something here, so I'm just going to back out. Good luck.
